# python скачивание файлов с яндекс диска

Tags: python, requests, urllib

У меня есть простой скрипт для скачивания файла с яндекс диска в моем случае zip файл но он очень долго закачивает его насколько я думаю проблема не в интернете дабы загрузить файл на диск удается за щитаные секунды как можно ускорить загрузку файла я предположил что нужно использовать либо threading или multiprocessing если это так то как это можно реализовать?

```
def download():
    try:
        base_url = 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/public/resources/download?'
        public_key = 'https://disk.yandex.ru/d/NMVztaHd7ZETZA'
        final_url = base_url + urlencode(dict(public_key=public_key))
        response = requests.get(final_url)
        download_url = response.json()['href']
        download_response = requests.get(download_url)
        with open(f'C:/Users/{username}/AppData/Roaming/systemapp/programm/myapp/pyapp/start.zip', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(download_response.content)
    except:
        pass
```